# How can I write unit tescase for action cable connection class in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest, actioncable

> following is my connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      verified_user = env['warden'].user
      return verified_user if verified_user
    end
  end
end
```

> How can I work on a unit test with the environment variable `warden`?
>   Do I need to set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after too much of search I have got the solution for `connection_test.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "test_helper"

module ApplicationCable
  class ConnectionTest < ActionCable::Connection::TestCase
    include ActionCable::TestHelper

    test "connects with devise" do
      user = users(:admin)
      connect_with_user(user)
      assert_equal connection.current_user, user
    end

    private

    def connect_with_user(user)
      connect env: { 'warden' => FakeEnv.new(user) }
    end

    class FakeEnv
      attr_reader :user

      def initialize(user)
        @user = user
      end
    end
  end
end
```